# Is there a more efficient way to wright this JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGdxL.png)[Picture of boxes]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X018k.png

As shown in the image I have three boxes. What I want to do is when I click a box it turns the background-color green, then when I click it again it goes back to its original state. The code I have works, but is there a more efficient way of writing the JavaScript?

HTML

```
 <div class="container">
      <div class="box first"></div>
      <div class="box second"></div>
      <div class="box third"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.colors {
  background: green;
}
```

JavaScript

```
const first = document.querySelector(".first");
const second = document.querySelector(".second");
const third = document.querySelector(".third");

first.addEventListener("click", () => {
  first.classList.toggle("colors");
});

second.addEventListener("click", () => {
  second.classList.toggle("colors");
});

third.addEventListener("click", () => {
  third.classList.toggle("colors");
});
```

Comment: Yes, [delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation) a single event to `.container`, and use event object passed to the handler function to recognize the clicked target element.

Comment: Or use a checkbox so that you won't need javascript at all.